# phonegap jquery cross domain html

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, cross-domain

at first: sorry for my bad english...
also im new in js, css, html, jquery, phonegap etc.

1. Cross domain should not be a problem because PhoneGap is a file base (file:///) where such restriction doesn't apply, right?
2. i know, that i need to whitelist the server in my config.xml like here
   http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_access_elements.md.html#Access%20Elements
3. but what is the best way to do it? A simple httprequest? A Plugin? ajax ?(I've haerd that ajax isnt good at file:/// requests).... i shall **not**
   use

   1. a proxy
   2. JSONP
   3. CORS (Cross-origin ressource sharing)

here you can see how the html code from the server will look like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Memorycards</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Memorycards</h1>
        <p>here are all Memorycards
            <li><a href="/memorycard/link1">memory1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/memorycard/link2">memory2</a></li>
        </p><a href="/newmemorycard/link3">new Memorycard <br></a>
     </body>
</html>
```

i want to put the names (memory1, memory2) in a list and the links (link1, link2) into another list.

Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: I believe you'll need to use one of the three things you don't want to use to get it to return REMOTE results to an application executing on a LOCAL device (cross site).  All local requests are in a sandboxed security environment.

Comment: what do you think should i use? cors is no option so i could use jsonp or a proxy. if i should use a proxy, is it enough to use corsproxy.com or do i need to write an own proxy in php?

Answer (score 0):

Something I've done in the past in ASP.NET is wrap all external json/xml requests with a local resource (like a proxy).  It makes the connection and simply returns the result which then you can use any javascript based application and bypass using jsonp.

Javascript <-> Local App <-> Remote Resource

For example, lets say you need to access the results on http://remotehost.com/app.php.  What you can do is write a local application that gets deployed with your javascript (let's call it remoteapp.php) that simply calls this resource and echos the response.  You then simply call remoteapp.php via your javascript using a simple ajax GET and you have the results of http://remotehost.com/app.php.

Given your limitations of not being able to use CORS and probably not wanting to rely on another application for XSS (corsproxy.com) this seems like your best bet.